# How much play is there in building bigger-than-Earth planets that support humans?

Tags: science-based, planets, gravity

Are there models, problems, and or engines for building life-sustaining 
worlds?

I believe that my approach is backwards. I have written a lot on my world and have been slowly working at making the humanoids, animals, plants and scale of the world all work.

This is the main question presently:

What would the makeup of a world need to be, to be 46.7 times the size of Earth, with 14% less gravity?

Comment: Volume or area?

Comment: By 46.7 times the size, you mean physical size, and not mass, right?

Comment: Random Inspired Question: How big could a mass of cotton candy get before it collapsed into a solid and/or became a planet?

Comment: Yes the reference is to physical size, not mass. Which, although i see your math, i believe we can play with the amount of mass that is iron to affect the gravity. If not then help me understand the fixed points of the algebra.

Comment: @MichealEldridge Is that a comment on my answer? If so, comment beneath it, and point out the specific parts you want clarification on.

Comment: How hard is the science of your setting?   The planet could be a construct with its interior bracing made of super materials to manage the forces while allowing for a much less dense (hollow even) interior spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Not much.

I assume that by "14% less gravity" you mean that at the surface, the force of gravity is only 0.86 times its strength on Earth's surface, i.e $g=0.86g_{\oplus}$. You also say that the size is 46.7 times the size of Earth, or $V=46.7V_{\oplus}$. Putting these requirements together tells us that the planet's mass and radius must be $M=11.2M_{\oplus}$ and  $R=3.6R_{\oplus}$. The density is therefore $0.239$ times that of Earth - that is, $1.32\text{ g cm}^{-3}$.

Looking at [various mass-radius relation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.2895v1.pdf) models, the planet should be composed largely of water, with a significant hydrogen/helium envelope. It's not significantly different from Uranus of Neptune in size, mass and density.

Such a planet will certainly be gaseous - it is far too big to be a [super-Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Earth), although it *could* be a [massive solid planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exoplanet#Massive_solid_planets) - because of how massive it is. It will likely have scooped up a fair amount of gas and dust from the original protoplanetary disk.

Comment: Ok, well then, the size of me planet can not change. For it is far to large a part of much of the settings in the book. The gravity is not fixed. That was just a random thing i had come up with.

Comment: @MichealEldridge So, the mass could change, then?

Comment: Yes if that would make the size work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going with the assumption that you mean volume 46.7 times the size of Earth.

I would say look at [Neptune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neptune).  It's [radius is 15299 miles vs Earth's 3959](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=neptune%20size%20compared%20to%20earth) miles

this gives Neptune a volume of 8432960097242.145 cubic miles, vs. Earth at 146132702751.045

This makes Neptune 57.7 times the volume of Earth, a little bigger than your request.

Neptune's gravity is 11.15 m/s and Earth's is 9.8 m/s, So Neptune is %13 greater than Earth.

So as a rough estimate making a planet just like Neptune but at 46.7 times the size of earth should be pretty close.  However, you really need to look at Neptune, since it is a gas giant and as such you will fall a long ways before you hit anything 'solid'...

To get a planet that large and 'solid' like earth, the gravity is going to be MUCH, MUCH more.

[Kepler-10c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler-10c#Characteristics)!  The largest rocky planet discovered to date.  it is estimated that it is 15-19 times the mass of Earth, it has about 2.5 times the radius which is 12-15 times the volume of Earth.

Comment: I think i understand, as far as "Much, Much more" goes. The composition of the planets core I believe could be adjusted. IE the amount of iron present in the core. Not the mass of iron itself, i realize that its mass is constant, no just the amount present combined with the rest of its said volume.

Comment: @MichealEldridge Well if it had a Lithium core you could get a bit bigger with less mass.

Comment: So lithium is less dense than iron i take it? (I will trust the facts presented, and not go look up all the elemental weights my self.) Not a scientist, just love the stuff and wish to learn so as to improve the real and wow factors of my world.

Comment: @MichealEldridge Yes Lithium is the lightest metal in existence. Third lightest element after Hydrogen and Helium

Comment: Not sure but I may have to invent a new element that has less weight but at least includes the properties of iron. So to have an atmosphere that can handle solar winds and such.

Comment: You can't invent a new, light element.  New elements will be heavy, and radioactive to boot.